# How to get a timestamp in Dart?

Tags: dart, epoch

I've been learning Dart, but I don't know how to generate a timestamp. I have tried this:

```
void main() {
  print((new Date()).millisecondsSinceEpoch);
}
```

Thanks to the IDE I was able to get this far, but
I'm getting a confusing error:

```
Exception: No such method: 'Date'
```

Help?

Answer (score 365, accepted):

You almost had it right. You just did not use a [named constructor](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html#ch02-constructors-named):

```dart
void main() {
  print(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch);
}
```

Gives:

> 1351441456747

See the API documentation for more: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.1/dart-core/DateTime-class.html

Comment: Is this UTC result?

Comment: `DateTime.now()` gives a moment in time in the local timezone and the first of January 1970, with which it is compared for calculating `millisecondsSinceEpoch` is in UTC. So the result is the moment in time as a UNIX timestamp, this does not have any timezone information associated since it is a number. It is up to you to convert the resulting moment in time back to a local time in a specific timezone.

Comment: *it gives a moment in time together with the associated local timezone in which it was created

Answer (score 12):

In order to get the timestamp in milliseconds from `DateTime`. Just use the `millisecondsSinceEpoch` property. Remember that this isn't a callable function rather a property.

```
DateTime time = DateTime.now();
time.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
```

January 1st, 1970 at 00:00:00 UTC is referred to as the Unix epoch. So, you'll get a number which corresponds to the milliseconds passed since Epoch. There is also a `microsecondsSinceEpoch` property.

Dart Documentation - https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.0/dart-core/DateTime/millisecondsSinceEpoch.html

Answer (score 11):

This is my solution

```
DateTime _now = DateTime.now();
print('timestamp: ${_now.hour}:${_now.minute}:${_now.second}.${_now.millisecond}');
```

Answer (score 5):

**Microseconds** is also available *natively* from Dart: (no need to import packages).

```
void main() {
  print(new DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch);
}
```

output:

> 1591457696860000

Comment: That comment should not stand as an answer, add a comment to the main answer or request an edit. Right now - it's duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

`void main() { print(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch); }`

Answer (score 1):

The answer may be posted very late it may help others. I have tried all the above answers which work perfectly to get the time stamp. But, to get your current time need to do some extra work you need to divide with 1000.

> DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch / 1000

Answer (score 0):

You can simply print the current timestamp in your timezone as a string like so:

print(DateTime.now().toString());

DateTime.Now() also has other methods like .day, .hour, .minute, etc.
.millisecondsSinceEpoch is one way to get it independent of timezone - this is how many milliseconds have passed since the "Unix epoch" 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z (UTC).