# Convert date string to milliseconds in Dart

Tags: string, date, dart

I would like to be able to convert a date string like this 'September 23, 2019' to milliseconds in dart

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a timestamp in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110542/how-to-get-a-timestamp-in-dart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `DateTime.parse('September 23, 2019').millisecondsSinceEpoch.`

or

```
var date = 'September 23, 2019';
var dateTimeFormat = DateFormat('MMMM d, yyyy', 'en_US').parse(date);
dateTimeFormat.millisecondsSinceEpoch
```

Also, someone answered this here -> [convert datetime string to datetime object in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49385303/convert-datetime-string-to-datetime-object-in-dart)

Comment: Thank you very much